# Unable to increment count on condition

Tags: r

The logic for the code below is:

- for each different client(can have more than 2 client)  which has `output == 1` the index value should increment as (3* client),
- if `output == 2`  then index value will be 10

The only condition that is not working is:

```
mydf$client[i]!=count
```

Yet it is not able to increment the count.

```
    mydf <- data.frame(time = c(2,4,3,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,3,2,4,3,2,4,4,2,2),
               output = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1),
               client =c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))
    mydf$index<-0
    count=1
    for (i in 1:length(mydf))
    { 
    repeat
    {
    if(mydf$client[i]==count)

    {

    if(mydf$output[i]==1 )
    {
    mydf$index[i]<-3*count

    }
    if(mydf$output[i]==2 )
    {
    mydf$index[i]<-10

    }
    }
    if(mydf$client[i]!=count )
    { 
    count<-count+1
    }
    if(mydf$client[i]<3)
    {break
    }
    }

    }
     Time output client index
       2     1     1      3
       4     1     1      3
       3     2     1      10
       2     2     1      10
       3     1     2      6
       3     1     2      6
       3     1     2      10
       4     1     2      10
       4     1     2      6     
       4     2     2      10 
       3     1     2      6
       2     1     2      6
       4     1     2      10
       3     1     2      6
       2     1     2      6
       4     2     2      10
       4     1     2      6
       2     1     2      6
       2     1     2      10
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Explain your code, what is it supposed to do, what is the expected output.

Comment: You show code that "is not working". However, you don't explain what exactly you want to achieve. How are we supposed to correct your code (or suggest better alternatives) then?

Comment: I added explanation, sorry about that!

Comment: Please show your desired output with actual values

Comment: I would do this in two simple fully vectorized steps `mydf$index <- mydf$client * 3 ; mydf$index[mydf$output == 2] <- 10` Though your output doesn't seem fully math your description

Comment: Thanks David, You made it really simple!!